# two approaches to database modeling - which one to use when

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

recently I have noticed a new approach to data modeling vs what I have used so far. This seems to be a way to address modeling of an entity that has a very large set of fields and quite often many of them are empty.

First approach - the one I used previously:

- Main table for the main set of fields (a,b=1,c=2)
- Additional table with a subset of fields  (a,e='foo',f='bar',...) - linked to Main one by a 1-1 relation
- Yet another Additional table with a subset of fields (a,j=3,k='baz',...) - linked to Main one by a 1-1 relation
- And one more with the rest of the fields (a,n=12.4, o='foobarbar', ...) - linked to main one by a 1-1 relation

The one I have seen recently is:

- Main table with almost no data except for an ID (a)
- Table that lists all the fields possible (b,'this is parameter b')
- a table that links the Main one with all the fields it has (a,b,1) and (a,c,2) and (a,e,'foo') and so on.

I understand you can query same results from both models, but I do not understand what is the rationale for the second one - are there clear cases where one of those should be used vs other? Thanks for your advice.

PS. The second one is being used on Oracle 11 - my last real life experiences with SQL were in the times of Postgres 7.x might be things changed meanwhile :)

Comment: Your second approach is called [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model)  Enter the term in google for exhaustive discussion of the EAV design model.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model it is. Thank you!

Comment: one more thing - to query this model efficiently for all attributes for entity 'a' I return all rows for the entity I look for and manage this in code rather than using a lot of joins, right?

Comment: EAV tables are not an Oracle specific concept.  It's just a much more highly normalised way of representing the data - with many benefits and issues.  As in the other comments, there is much on-line that discusses EAV.  It's something that is initially very attractive to generalists, but it really does have its costs too.

Comment: Here's a case study of an EAV implementation: http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: If you ever think you need an EAV in a relational database, then you don't need them. You'll want to switch to a Key-Value database. Creating an EAV in a relational database is just forcing an RDBMS to do things against its natural design.

Answer (score 1):

The second format you're outlining is a fairly common Data Warehouse strategy.

It's used to de-normalise data when you have an extremely large (or complex) set that needs to be stored over a long period of time, during which there may be a number of schema changes, or if you want to warehouse an entire schema into a much smaller set of tables.

In the wild it's a fairly rare to come across during application development as it is extremely slow to query compared to a standard relational model, you don't have the luxury of indexes or the query optimiser so it becomes difficult to select a sub-set of data. This is obviously only a problem if query speed is a primary concern, so certain domains will benefit massively from a de-normalised data format (medical record storage and insurance company data are two examples I can think of off the top of my head).

If I were dealing with a sparse-matrix-style dataset (which I don't often have to at my current job, but have done in the past) I'd probably go with the google-style BigTable if you're aware of the possible column set before the DDL is created, or can do column additions as a long-running batch during application downtime. That way you still have the ability to index and query effectively, which, given that you've said this is Oracle related, you really want to be able to do!

Comment: It's fairly rare common?

Comment: -1 @Mike Woodcock: Either you have misunderstood the question, or you have seen some pretty weird datawarehouses - since you talk about denormalisation, I think it's the former. The OP is **not** talking about denormalisation, but about EAVs.

Comment: @Mark apparently you've misunderstood my name. Plus, the pattern the OP outlined is a form of de-normalisation, and I work with an application that has the exact pattern used in its DW for the reasons outlined.

Comment: @Mike, yeah, that was a fairly bad typo! I'll edit.

Comment: @Ed, yes, I mangled your name, but no, it's not a form of denormalisation - EAV is pretty close to a mangled form of 6NF.

Comment: @MarkBannister no problem. De-normalisation may not be the exactly correct name, but it's definitely what I'd think of as de-normalisation. You no longer have the table-column-row structure explicitly defining characteristics of your entities, but instead defining them as meta-data of generic "entity" entities. I'm not seeing the 6NF comparison, since there will be no foreign key relations whatsoever except the modelling of the table structure from the entity-attribute mapping data however, my high-integer-NF knowledge is fairly rusty!).

Comment: -(-1) (ie. removed downvote) - it definitely sounds like you have seen some unusual DWHs; performance is normally a key requirement.

Comment: @MarkBannister thanks, I didn't think I was that far off the mark. The devs of the DWs I've worked with are normally bothered about input speed and flexibility, they don't want to have to mess with the DW schema if there are changes to the schema of the DB being warehoused since doing a column addition in tables with more than a few billion rows takes a very long time. Output speed is normally less of a concern since any reports will generally be overnight batch jobs.

Comment: I'm with Mark, EAV is probably the *opposite* of denormalization. Magento, for example, has special jobs just to denormalize its EAV tables in order to improve performance.  I'm thinking maybe you are confusing it with [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Answer (score 1):

The two approaches each have advantages and disadvantages.  The first approach is far more common.

First approach give you:

- Type safety for each column/entity attribute
- Ability to specify different constraints for different attributes
- Proper sorting of each attribute (e.g. dates can be sorted by year/month/day when stored as a DateTime; this is much more difficult in EAV where everything is a string)
- Ability to enforce referential integrity for different attributes or keys
- Ability to promote an attribute to a key when needed
- Possibly different collation/language/sort order for each column
- Ability to use indexes, and tailor them for specific attributes
- Different DB statistics and optimizations depending on the nature of each column
- Much easier joins
- Higher performance

Second approach (also known as [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) gives you:

- Ability for the end user to add more attributes at run time

EAV also has a lot of problems!!!  See [my answer to this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341451/compromise-between-formal-correctness-and-convenience-in-database-relations/341464) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading it right the second format looks like something you would use if you don't know what are all the fields for the main entity.  This would be the case if you want the user to specify properties of the main entity.

Comment: Extendible numbers of properties is definitely one property.  But it also removes the need for a NULL value - Simply don't have the value in the EAV table.  There are many more properties (positive and negative) than a SO answer (or comment) could list, it really is something to check on the web rather than here.